How to dynamically split Readable stream into multiple streams depending on the count limit
I have Readable stream which provides objects to another Transform stream (which is CsvFormatterStream<I, O> from @fast-csv/format npm package). Then the csv stream is piped to fs Writeable stream to write CSV file. Please see the example at the bottom of the post.
I'm looking for a solution to split the objects from Readable stream into chunks of size n, so it will produce CSV files with max data rows count = n.
For example:

n = 10,
total objects count produced by Readable stream = 32

It should produce 4 CSV files: 3 CSV files with rows count = 10 and 1 CSV file with rows count = 2.
How can I achive this?

UPD. I would like to have a custom stream with configurable n which will receive objects from another stream and produce y readable streams, where y number of chunks of max size n
I've already implemented it and will post it later when SO will allow me to do this.

Example:
Prerequisites:

npm i @fast-csv/format

const { Readable } = require('node:stream');
const {format} = require('@fast-csv/format');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises');

(async () => {
  try {
    const readable = new Readable({ objectMode: true });
    const csvStream = format({ headers: true });
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), 'test.csv'), {
      flags: 'w',
    });

    const objects = createObjects(32);
    objects.forEach(obj => readable.push(obj));
    readable.push(null);

    await pipeline(readable, csvStream, fileStream);
    console.log('Success!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();

function createObjects(n) {
  const objects = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const obj = createObject(i);
    objects.push(obj);
  }

  return objects;
}

function createObject(i) {
  return {
    id: i,
    name: `Obj #${i}`,
  };
}


Does it absolutely have to be the readable that is split? Could easily create 4 readables, for 4 writables.

This question is similar to: CSV write stream - split into multiple files and combine in one archive (e. g. zip). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Salketer Not sure, but right now I send SQL query to Snowflake and get 1 readable stream. This readable should be transformed to one or multiple CSV files with max lines count = n. Right now it's placing everything to a single CSV file. I'll take a look at the question you've sent in the previous comment, thank you!

Then I think the answer given in that question will easily get you there. Just create the writeable stream instead of the passthrough and you'll be gold.

@Salketer it helped me a little bit, but it doesn't fully solve my issue. I've got some ideas from that answer and have written my own implementation based on Transform class. I would like to post the answer here because it might be helpul for the other developers

The splitting can be done by implementing the Transform stream which will accumulate chunks and release them as another stream. Then we can iterate through the results using asynchronous iterator.
SplitterStream class:
class SplitterStream extends Transform {
  constructor(limit, opts) {
    super({readableObjectMode: true, writableObjectMode: true});
    this.limit = limit;
    this.opts = opts;
    this.pushedCount = 0;
    this.currStream = new PassThrough(this.opts);
  }

  _transform(row, _encoding, callback) {
    this.currStream.write(row);
    this.pushedCount++;

    if (this.pushedCount === this.limit) {
      this.currStream.end();
      this.push(this.currStream);
      this.currStream = new PassThrough(this.opts);
      this.pushedCount = 0;
    }
    callback();
  }

  _flush(callback) {
    // If last rows were not pushed - push them before the end
    if (this.pushedCount > 0) {
      this.push(this.currStream);
      this.currStream = null;
      this.pushedCount = 0;
    }
    callback();
  }
}

Example of usage. It produces 4 files as expected
const { Readable, Transform, PassThrough, Writable } = require('node:stream');
const {format} = require('@fast-csv/format');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises');

class SplitterStream extends Transform {
  constructor(limit, opts) {
    super({readableObjectMode: true, writableObjectMode: true});
    this.limit = limit;
    this.opts = opts;
    this.pushedCount = 0;
    this.currStream = new PassThrough(this.opts);
  }

  _transform(row, _encoding, callback) {
    this.currStream.write(row);
    this.pushedCount++;

    if (this.pushedCount === this.limit) {
      this.currStream.end();
      this.push(this.currStream);
      this.currStream = new PassThrough(this.opts);
      this.pushedCount = 0;
    }
    callback();
  }

  _flush(callback) {
    // If last rows were not pushed - push them before the end
    if (this.pushedCount > 0) {
      this.push(this.currStream);
      this.currStream = null;
      this.pushedCount = 0;
    }
    callback();
  }
}

(async () => {
  try {
    // Create and fill readable
    const readable = new Readable({ objectMode: true });
    const splitterStream = new SplitterStream(15, {readableObjectMode: true, writableObjectMode: true});

    const objects = createObjects(32);
    objects.forEach(obj => readable.push(obj));
    readable.push(null);

    readable.pipe(splitterStream);

    let i = 1;
    for await (const _readable of splitterStream) {
      const csvStream = format({ headers: true });
      const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), `test_${i++}.csv`), {
        flags: 'w',
      });

      await pipeline(_readable, csvStream, fileStream);
    }
    
    console.log('Success!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();

function createObjects(n) {
  const objects = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const obj = createObject(i);
    objects.push(obj);
  }

  return objects;
}

function createObject(i) {
  return {
    id: i,
    name: `Obj #${i}`,
  };
}

